# Convert co-ordinates to isometric and vice versa not working

Tags: javascript, math, isometric

I have two functions which recieve co-ordinates that are not returning the correct output.

One receives the position of the mouse relative to the element and returns a grid co ordinate for isometric tiles.
The other function essentially reverses this process from iso tile back to pixel position on the screen.

When i send in a co-ordinate for my mouse position and convert it to isometric, then convert it back to pixel position i get a different result from what i started with by a large margin rather than the rounding of the tile size - suggesting I got the maths wrong some where, but am not sure where.

My two functions are:

```
function isoToScreen(isoX,isoY){ //recieves simple grid co-ordinate (int,int)

var x = (isoX - isoY) * (grid.getWidth()/2),
    y = (isoX + isoY) * (grid.getHeight()/2);

    //need to remove the camera offset to get the relative position
    x = camera.removeOffsetX(x); 
    y = camera.removeOffsetY(y); 

    return {'x':x,'y':y};

}

function screenToIso(x,y){ //receives mouse position relative to canvas

    //add camera offset to get the correct isometric grid
    x = camera.addOffsetX(x);
    y = camera.addOffsetY(y);

var isoX = x / (grid.getWidth()/2)  + y /  (grid.getHeight()/2),
    isoY = y / (grid.getHeight()/2) - x /  (grid.getWidth()/2);

    return {'x':Math.floor(isoX),'y':Math.floor(isoY)}
}
```

Just some extra info, `grid height == 46` and `grid width == 92`.

Can any one see where i am going wrong in the my maths logic?

Comment: In your function screenToIso(x,y) I feel like you should wrap the math operations within brackets because there is nested division. To my experience it makes difference. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/zba7jcyr/

Comment: @Puni thanks for the reply i tried your alteration but it's not fixed the problem. I'll update my question with the brackets added to rule that issue out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `screenToIso` you are multiplying the vector `[x;y]` by the matrix:

```
[  2 / grid.getWidth(), 2 / grid.getHeight()]
[ -2 / grid.getWidth(), 2 / grid.getHeight()]
```

Its [inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_2.C3.972_matrices) is:

```
[grid.getWidth()  / 4, -grid.getWidth()  / 4]
[grid.getHeight() / 4,  grid.getHeight() / 4]
```

Hence the first two lines of `isoToScreen` should be:

```
var x = (grid.getWidth()  / 4) * isoX - (grid.getWidth()  / 4) * isoY;
var y = (grid.getHeight() / 4) * isox + (grid.getHeight() / 4) * isoY;
```